# Grouping by multiple columns in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model with a few columns:

```
Model (id, country, city, name, age)
```

I need to group and sort by a few columns:

```
SELECT * FROM Model
WHERE country = 'USA'
GROUP BY id, city, age
ORDER BY id, city, age
```

and I'd like to query the same with Django ORM.

```
Model.objects.filter(country='USA').group_by('id', 'city', 'age').order_by('id', 'city', 'age')
```

But this call throws after `group_by` as it returns `None`.

Comment: What exactly would you expect this to return?

Comment: Why do you need to use `GROUP BY`? Grouping by `id` makes it completely redundant as all ids are unique.

Comment: I have't seen a  group_by method on filter yet